# Запуск игрового сервера с++

Tags: c++, linux

Здравствуйте! 
Я на php написал скрипт управлением игровым сервером.

Решил под него написать сервер на c++.

Все как бы не плохо, кроме одного, когда я запускаю игровой сервер через ПУ и останавливаю свой сервер, игровой начинает висеть на порту сервера.

И что бы заново запустить сервер управления нужно убить сервер игры.

Помогите решить проблему.

Функция exec:

```
string exec(const char *cmd) {
    char buffer[2048];
    std::string result = "";
    FILE *pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    try {
        while (!feof(pipe)) {
            if (fgets(buffer, 2048, pipe) != NULL)
                result += buffer;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

Запуск сервера:

```
server = new net::serversocket(8888);
while (true) {
   net::socket *client = server->accept();

   string readMessage = "";
   string sendMessage = "";

   client->read(readMessage);

   std::vector <std::string> command = split(readMessage, '|');
   int startI = 0;
   if (command[0] == "start") {

      int forkStartServer = fork();

      if(forkStartServer < 0){

      }else if (forkStartServer == 0){
          setsid();
          forkStartServer = fork();

          if(forkStartServer < 0){

          }else if (forkStartServer == 0){
              exec(command[1].c_str());
          }
      }
   sendMessage = "start 1";
   client->send(sendMessage);
   client->close();
   }
}
```

Команда ss -p:
После остановки сервера управления и при запущенном игровом сервере заполнена такими записями

```
tcp   CLOSE-WAIT 1  0   127.0.0.1:8888   127.0.0.1:35044 users:(("gs",pid=17536,fd=13),("glinkd",pid=17535,fd=13),("gdeliveryd",pid=17526,fd=13),("gfactiond",pid=17524,fd=13),("gacd",pid=17523,fd=13),("java",pid=17521,fd=13),("gamedbd",pid=17517,fd=13),("uniquenamed",pid=17504,fd=13),("logservice",pid=17497,fd=13))
```

Comment: Что такое `net`?

Comment: namespace класса сокета

Comment: начиная с блока try  много ошибок и лишнего. Во первых в блоке try уберите цикл, потому что после первого цикла уже генерируются исключения, а вы в catch обрабатываете их только одной операцией, а именно закрываете файл... поэтому catch(std::runtyme_error) будет хотябы более логичным, но в вашем примере вообше не имеет смысла генерировать исключение, а просто  if (!pipe) закрыть файл и exit(1); поскольку вы всеравно не пытаетесь ловить исключения которые сгенерировали повторно в блоке catch, exec вызываете не в блоке try, ну и т. д.

Comment: Это поправил, но проблему с занятым портом не решил...

Comment: Не знаю что такое `net` но в базовых функциях для работы с сокетами есть флаг "close on exec" (FD_CLOEXEC), который ставится на сокет с помощью `fcntl()`. Его надо выставлять на всех сокетах, коорых не должно быть у вызванного exec процесса

Comment: Спасибо, реально помогло FD_CLOEXEC